# Can't overload python object while using pickle

Tags: python, pickle

Taking inputs through input command and calling object from main file.

```
rafTur = input(' : ')
rafKat = input(' : ')
rafNo = input( : ')
rafIndex = input(' : ')
req.search_record(' : ')
req.search_record(rafTur, rafKat, rafNo, rafIndex)
```

req.py :

```
def search_record( rafTur, rafKat, rafNo, rafIndex= None):
   infile = open('noSqlDB', 'rb')
   flag = False

   while True:
       try:
           reading the oject from file

        sistem = pickle.load(infile)
        if sistem['rafTur'] == rafTur and sistem['rafKat'] == rafKat and sistem['rafNo'] == rafNo and rafIndex==None: # This is where the error happens
            print("Raf No : ",sistem['rafIndex'],"Raf data : ",sistem['rafIndexData'])
            print(":", rafIndex)
            flag = True
            break
        # display record if found and set flag
        if (sistem['rafTur'] == rafTur and sistem['rafKat'] == rafKat and sistem['rafNo'] == rafNo and sistem['rafIndex'] == rafIndex):
            print(sistem['rafIndexData'],"\n")
            flag = True
            break

    except EOFError:
        print("deb")
        break

   if flag == False:
       print('Record not Found')
       print()


   infile.close()
```

I'm trying to overload `search_record()` function. When I put `= None` to `rafIndex` variable the program exits with `OFError` and prints `deb` ( just for debugging ). The code works fine without `= None` command also second if works without `= None` command.

I tried changing if statement with `== None` to `== ''` it also doesn't work. I also tried assigning rafIndex to `None` manually by `rafIndex = None` but it also doesn't work.

[image: Output]

Using python 3.9 virtualenv in Clion

Comment: You have to use some string for signifying that there is no value, either you enter `None` string in console then your variable will be equal to `"None"` string (in this case you should compare `if var == "None":`), or you just hit enter then you'll have empty string inside variable `""` (in this case you should compare `if var == "":`). But you have to decide how and what string should signify emptiness.

Comment: Like i said. I tired changing the if statement with `==""` it also doesn't work.

Comment: It depends what you have entered in console. To see exactly what you entered do `print(string.encode('utf-8'))` where `string` is variable that you filled with entered value. Do this printing right after entering value and also after unpickling. If you just hit enter then this print statement should output `b''` meaning 0-bytes. Print statement will output bytes representation of your string, to be precise. Just do this printing and tell us what did it print out. Print after inputing value from console and after un-pickling value, in both places. And tell us what you see printed.

Comment: Yeah. I was using utf-8 encoding. I didn't know it changes output like that. When i tried printing with encoding it gave me b'3' output for 3 input like [this](https://prnt.sc/114k8ya)

Comment: Now, when you have problem that you mentioned in your Question, try to output to console problematic string. For example if you entered blank (by just pressing Enter), then print this string with blank, what do you see printed on console? Also print this problematic string right after un-pickling, print it same way through encoding to utf-8, what do you see on console? If you see `b''` for example, then you can compare such string using `if rafIndex == '':`.

Comment: I solved the problem with casting variables to int and string. and using `==""` equation. Thanks for your helps

Comment: If you don't mind you can share short steps that you used to solve your task, share by creating your own answer to your question. User that created Question can Answer his own question too. So that new people who read you question may know the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the main problem is the variables and input was different type. So casting them to int and string will solve the problem.

Created a function for casting :

```
def toCast(rafTur, rafKat, rafNo, rafIndex):
    if rafTur != "":
        rafTur = str(rafTur) #Change this

    if rafKat != "":
        rafKat = int(rafKat)

    if rafNo != "":
        rafNo = int(rafNo)

    if rafIndex != "":
        rafIndex = int(rafIndex)


    return  rafTur,rafKat,rafNo,rafIndex
```

That function makes casting if function isn't empty after that i used this function in main like this :

```
elif choice == '3':

            rafTur = input('Rafın türünü giriniz : ')
            rafKat = input('Rafın katını giriniz : ')
            rafNo = input('Rafın Nosunu giriniz : ')
            rafIndex = input('Rafın indexini giriniz : ') 
            rafTur,rafKat,rafNo,rafIndex = req.toCast(rafTur, rafKat, rafNo, rafIndex)

            req.search_record(rafTur, rafKat, rafNo, rafIndex)
```

after that i rechanged if else's in `search_record(rafTur, rafKat, rafNo, rafIndex)` with this :

```
 def search_record(rafTur, rafKat, rafNo, rafIndex):
    infile = open('noSqlDB', 'rb')
    sistem = pickle.load(infile)
    flag = False

    # read to the end of file.
    for x in range((len(sistem)+1)):
        try:

            if (sistem['rafTur'].upper() == rafTur.upper() and rafKat == "" and rafNo == ""
                    and rafIndex == ""):

                print(sistem['rafTur'],sistem['rafNo'], sistem['rafIndex'], sistem['rafIndexData'])
                flag = True


            elif (sistem['rafTur'].upper() == rafTur.upper() and sistem['rafKat'] == rafKat and
                    rafNo == "" and rafIndex == ""):

                print(sistem['rafNo'], sistem['rafIndex'], sistem['rafIndexData'])
                flag = True

            elif (sistem['rafTur'].upper() == rafTur.upper() and sistem['rafKat'] == rafKat and sistem[
                'rafNo'] == rafNo and rafIndex == ""):

                print(sistem['rafIndex'], sistem['rafIndexData'])
                flag = True

            elif (sistem['rafTur'].upper() == rafTur.upper() and sistem['rafKat'] == rafKat and sistem[
                'rafNo'] == rafNo and sistem['rafIndex'] == rafIndex):

                print(sistem['rafIndexData'])
                flag = True

            sistem = pickle.load(infile)
        except EOFError:
            break

    if flag == False:
        print('Record not Found')
        print()

    # close the file
    infile.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is with the previous line where you try to load the pickled object.
It would be very helpful if you can instead of catching the exception paste the stack trace here. Also for debugging it will be helpful for you if you print the 'sistem' object after performing the pickle.load

Comment: It prints every object of `sistem` without error and the loop works but if statement. [Like this](https://imgur.com/a/Y1SwGcG).

Comment: As I said if you paste the stack trace it will be much simpler to understand

Comment: Sorry but i don't know what stack trace is. I'm googling it right now if i learn how to do it. I will add it to question.

Comment: You can either remove the try except clause or reraise the exception after you catch it and see the output. The exception traceback will show you exactly from which line of code the error is coming from. EOF error just means you reached the end of the file. Also I recommend using open as a context, that way you don't have to deal with closing the file by youtself

Comment: So i tried exception traceback. Is [this](https://imgur.com/a/oDspP2N) what you want sir

Comment: Yes, so as you can see the line of code that fails is 'sistem = pickle.load(infile)' since you've probably reached the end of the file. The next step I recommend is to print the object after you are loading it (before the if statements) I suspect you have some wrong assumptions regarding your data.

Comment: I already did it on [this](https://imgur.com/a/Y1SwGcG) photo. It's the output of `sistem` right before the if. I think the problem is on if statement but i don't know what.

Comment: From what I see you have 2 records in your db both have rafIndex with values of  so 15 and 17 and since your input is empty for rafIndex none of the if statements hold. After that the file ends. What exactly are you expecting?

Comment: Overloading the function. It has 5 input. I'm trying to write it with 4-3-2 input variation.